# How to properly use the clienthandler for certifcates when doing a web request with powershell?

Tags: powershell, x509certificate, dotnet-httpclient, x509, client-certificates

My web request using a certificate, implemented in powershell code, gives an error about a certificate missing. It is supposed to work because similar code in C# does not cause this problem.

Here is my powershell code:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Net.Http
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Net.Primitives
$cert = Get-Item -Path "Cert:\CurrentUser\My\$thumbprint"
$clientHandler = New-Object System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler
$clientHandler.ClientCertificates.Add($cert)
$client = New-Object System.Net.Http.HttpClient($clientHandler)
$message = New-Object System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage
$message.Method = [System.Net.Http.HttpMethod]::Get
$message.RequestUri = New-Object System.Uri($url)
$response = $client.SendAsync($message)
$responseContent = $response.Result.Content
$content = $responseContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result
$content
```

Here is the response.

```
<html>
<head><title>400 No required SSL certificate was sent</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<center>No required SSL certificate was sent</center>
<hr><center>nginx/XXXX</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I do not get this response when using the certificate in my browser. My C# application also works fine. So how do I make this powershell script work?

**Update**

An alternative approach to execute the web request using powershell gives the same error. Here is the alternative approach:

```
$cert = Get-Item -Path "Cert:\CurrentUser\My\$thumbprint"
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method GET -Certificate $cert
```

Comment: You could use the `Invoke-WebRequest` command with the cert parameter and your variable $cert or the thumbprint parameter with the $thumbprint variable

Comment: URL has to be HTTPS (not HTTP).  If you are sending HTTPS there may be a proxy the needs to be turned off.

Comment: @jdweng I use HTTPS of course. Otherwise, I would have the same problem in my web browser.

Comment: @guiwhatsthat I just tried that too. See update in my post. Same problem.

Comment: Use Post instead of GET.  You have a body in the request which required a Post. This should not give error that you are getting.  Are you an Admin.  Try starting PS by right click shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Comment: Can you post the “similar code in c#” that works? Might be easier to spot the problem if there’s something to compare it to…